# в java - class JPanel не видит метода setColor

Tags: java

пишу

```
class myPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) 
    {
        gr.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        gr.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }
}
```

не проходит проверку на синтаксис - подчеркивает метод `setColor`
пишет:

> cannot find symbol symbol: method setColor(Color) location: variable
>   gr of type Graphics

Не пойму в чем дело? Необходимые импорты сделал.
Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Полный текст ошибки в студию

Comment: .setBackground(new Color(204, 0, 0(ТВОЙ ЦВЕТ)));
Пробуй так

Comment: Полный тест ошибки:
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setColor(Color)
  location: variable gr of type Graphics

при использовании setBackground ошибка осталась та же.
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setBackground(Color)
  location: variable gr of type Graphics

Comment: Покажите импорты

Comment: import com.sun.prism.Graphics;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

Comment: Чуда не произошло - это не тот Graphics, нужен вот этот `java.awt.Graphics` )

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло. А то я начинающий программист(временно) и пока в импортах особо не понимаю))